# Write row number to table using INSERT statement with SELECT & UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to write sequential row numbers based on a column to a temporary table ##TAX_TEMP using an INSERT statement that contains a SELECT query with multiple unions. However, I am getting a repeating sequence per UNION like so:

| PAYGROUP | BATCH_ID | FILE_NBR | PAY_NBR | ENTRY_NBR | PDE_TRANS_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 1 | 1 | P |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 2 | 1 | P |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 1 | 1 | P |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 2 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 1 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 2 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 1 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 2 | 1 | P |

Where I am looking for it to write sequentially based on the `FILE_NBR` column, like so:

| PAYGROUP | BATCH_ID | FILE_NBR | PAY_NBR | ENTRY_NBR | PDE_TRANS_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 1 | 1 | P |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 2 | 1 | P |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 3 | 1 | P |
| GA5 | MST_GA5PDE_07192022 | 000597 | 4 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 1 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 2 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 3 | 1 | P |
| GBZ | MST_GBZPDE_07192022 | 002418 | 4 | 1 | P |

The query for the above result is:

```
             SELECT PAYGROUP,
                    BATCH_ID,
                    FILE_NUM,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FILE_NBR),
                    ENTRY_NBR,
                    PDE_TRANS_TYPE,
```

I attempted the following:

```
INSERT INTO ##TAX_TEMP
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FILE_NBR) as 'PAY_NBR', * FROM (
                   SELECT PAYGROUP, BATCH_ID, FILE_NBR, ENTRY_NBR, PDE_TRANSTYPE
                   FROM TAX_TABLE
)
```

But I am getting a syntax error that is expecting an 'as' or QUOTED_ID

Comment: and if you change [as 'PAY_NBR'] to [as PAY_NBR] do you still get the error? Not a sql-server user here, but aliases don't like ticks in my environments.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, post the complete error message that you encounter - not an abbreviated one. Next, your attempt to use a derived table (that SELECT statement in parentheses) serves no useful purpose. You could just add an alias for it to cure the error but why bother with the added complexity. So try:

```
INSERT INTO ##TAX_TEMP (...) 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FILE_NBR) as PAY_NBR, 
       PAYGROUP, BATCH_ID, FILE_NBR, ENTRY_NBR, PDE_TRANSTYPE 
FROM dbo.TAX_TABLE;
```

I've made some minor changes to implement better habits. Schema-qualify tables. Don't use single quotes to define an alias. Always supply a complete column list for INSERT and SELECT statements. Terminate every statement. Better habits make better code.

And to fix your numbering problem, it seems you need to add partitioning to your ROW_NUMBER usage. How exactly to do that is unclear. You mention UNION but your query has none.